# Running docker-compose up with Python's 'fabric'

Tags: python, docker-compose, command-line-interface, fabric

I am using Docker (+ Docker Compose). All `docker-compose` interaction occurs via the Python '[fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/)' package (v1).

Example:

```
def runserver():
    local('docker-compose up')
```

and:

```
$ fab runserver
```

Everything behaves normally until I attempt to `^C` out of a running `docker-compose up`:

1. `docker-compose` appears to receive the `^C` (`SIGINT`?) signal as it starts stopping my containers - e.g.:

```
Stopping celery-export ... done
Stopping celery        ...
```

However during the container stopping process (sometimes as long as 10 seconds if a container doesn't respond to signals properly), I can press enter / return and see / interact with my shell (as if the process has ended).

Though at this stage the containers haven't finished stopping yet (there's not a `done` next to each `Stopping ...` line). It's as if I've prematurely been given access to my shell, which I can freely use. If a late-finishing container eventually stops (usually after 10 seconds), it'll draw the `done` line over what I'm currently doing in my terminal.

Example:

```
Stopping celery-export ... done
Stopping celery        ...
Stopping redis         ...

$ uptime 
10:54  up 1 day, 17:22, 2 users, load averages: 1.73 1.94 1.92
Stopping celery        ... done
Stopping redis         ... done
```

This does not occur when I call `docker-compose up` directly (outside of fabric) so I suspect that it's something to do with fabric wrapping the execution of the command.

The expected behaviour being that I cannot access my shell until after the container stopping process finishes.

Forgive my lack of proper terminology for describing this issue, and if this'd be more appropriate on Superuser instead of SO.

Comment: The ^C is handled by fabric and ends it, returning the control to the shell. This will also send a signal to its child docker-compose that will clean up and end when finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fabric 1.x has split into two projects, 'Invoke' (`inv`) is the replacement package for running local commands, and what is relevant here.

Invoke has made drastic improvements in this area, and no longer has this issue. It is relatively easy to migrate from Fabric 1.x to Invoke. I do not see the potential for any fix in Fabric 1.x. My solution was to use Invoke instead.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to answer, my answer it's my vision of your problem:

1. fabric run a command by configuration and stop.
2. docker-compose up command: [Builds, (re)creates, starts, and attaches to containers for a service](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/). When a keyword is **attach**. When you run:

```
docker-compose up
```

Then the last operation is `attach` to the container (service).
For example next docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "3.6"


services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

if you run `docker-compose up` you'll see next output:

```
Starting fabric_nginx_1 ... done
Attaching to fabric_nginx_1
```

When `Attaching to fabric_nginx_1` is successfully ended attachment to nginx server.
Ctrl-C or SIGINT sent to this console will stop nginx process and container (service).

For run process/container/service as a daemon, you should run docker-compose detached and use -d/--detach switch.

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Then your service will run as a service. For stop, you will should use:

1. [docker-compose stop](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/stop/) or
2. [docker-compose kill](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/kill/) or
3. [docker-compose down](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/)

Conclusion: In your case, all work as designed. Fabric runs a docker-compose command and stop. `docker-compose` create containers, run them and stop. The container behavior is by his own content packed into container.

Comment: `docker-compose up`—when used by itself—is behaving as designed, yes. I did not mean to intend that I wish for my containers to continue to execute after I ^C out of the process.

The issue is that—in the event that I ^C docker-compose (when run via fabric) I am able to press enter and use my shell before the containers have stopped.

This also results in some peculiar terminal drawing bugs when docker-compose tries to write 'done' to an existing line, and it makes it hard to actually tell which containers have stopped without doing a `docker ps` or similar.

Comment: Sorry, I totally failed to understand what a problem. Do you need to stop container? Or problem when you can type in same bash session when 'fabric' was run?

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, using Ctrl+C seems to be killing Fabric in your case. The SSH command still runs in the background and you're getting its output to the console until it finishes.

Instead of doing it this way, I suggest you use `docker-compose up -d` so Fabric finishes once all the containers are up. If you want to tail the logs, you should add another Fabric command that will execute `docker-compose logs`. When you Ctrl+C that one, it should end quickly and not run in the background like `up`. When you want to stop the containers, use `docker-compose stop`.

Answer (score -1):

I use `docker-compose up` (outside of Fabric) while testing.  Often when I ctrl+C not all of the images are terminated before I'm returned to the command prompt.  In fact, Redis often stays up and running in the background.  Rerunning `docker-compose up` even results in the display of the Redis messages accumulated since the ctrl+C.

In my case, a suitable workaround to make sure everything is "dead", I use `docker kill $(docker ps -q)`.  That kills any running images.